# Can Uromastyx eat peanuts?

Tags: diet, reptiles, lizards

I bought my Uro a Finch seed mix since I read seeds can be a good addition to a Uro's diet in terms of nutrients and roughage. I've been giving it to her for a few months now, and noticed that she particularly likes one of the ingredients; large beige chunks.

I decided to go over the ingredients again, and realized there are a few "odd" ingredients in it that I missed the first time I bought it. My biggest concern, since it seems like an unnatural part of their diet and what she seems to be the most fond of, is "ground hulled peanuts".

Is this cause for concern/switching brands/recipes? She absolutely *loves* this mix, so I'd rather not switch if  it's ok, but I also don't want to hurt her.
She isn't given insects, so I don't think overconsumption of protein would be an issue.

I did some searching, and found forum posts of lizards eating (and loving) peanut butter, but obviously this doesn't prove that it's good for them, or not harmful.

Here's the back of the bag. I underlined a few questionable ingredients, including the peanuts. I know both corn and rice are often used as filler, but looking through the mix, I can't see anything that looks like either of them; I can only see seeds and fruit chunks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's particularly harmful if it's not a large component of her diet. The problems with seed mixes is you have to research the nutritional components of each item, which is time consuming. Peanuts do have a high oxalate (oxalic acid) and goitrogen content. You can use a sifter or a colander with small holes to remove the large chunks if you feel she is eating too much of it. This removes the oat groats which could expand in the gut. A few will probably be fine.

Also this is a supplemented feed so be sure you adjust your other supplements if you are feeding this as more than 10% of her total diet.